# How to put image using qt4 in raspberry pi

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, qt4, putty

I have raspberry pi3 and i am making GUI in raspberry pi using qt4. GUI containing two buttons and one image. Button is available in qt4 designer but i don't know how to put image using qt4 designer. Please tell me how to put image using qt4 designer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding your image as a resource to your project and setting this image as a background image to your mainwidget.

1. Right click on your project, and click "add new.."
2. Select Qt under Files and Classes and select Qt Resource File template.
3. After naming and finishing template creation. You should have a ".qrc" file in you project. Click on it and you will see resource editor.
4. On editor click to "Add" and add a prefix with a name you prefer.
5. Click to "Add" again and by clicking "Add files" add you image as a resource.
6. Go to designer, right click on your mainwidget "Change styleSheet".
7. Click on arrow near Add Resource to open dropdown menu. Then select "background-image" you should see your image as a resource in there.
8. Select your image and it should appear as background of your GUI

If you don't want it as a background image add a "Widget" to your GUI and do the same styleSheet edit to it.

Answer (score 0):

Would this perhaps help? Not sure if it is just for Qt 5.x or not, might be worth a shot though.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html

Comment: Thanks...but this is not helpful for me. Because i have used qt4 and this is in qt5.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/459-Qt4-1-How-to-insert-an-image-inside-a-Form

These guys infer you can set an image with the pixmap property. OP is using Qt 4.